# Visual Studio 2019 Intellisense color-coding / toolbox not working

Tags: macos, visual-basic, visual-studio-2019

I have just downloaded Visual Studio 2019 on my Mac and I'm having problems with visual Basic.

Visual Studio doesn't color the code that's always white (in my case, for Visual Basic), and also, I can't find any GUI (the window where you can drop elements like TextBox etc.)

That's what i am looking for:

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rew_iMkZ3aw/maxresdefault.jpg

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke My question is: Where can i find the window (if there is one) of the graphical interface of visual basic? Watch this image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rew_iMkZ3aw/maxresdefault.jpg Here you have the window with the toolbpx with all the elements, i don't have it in my visual studio. And my code is not coloured too.

Comment: Ok, great. Feel free to edit that into your question. Now to the next part: what have you tried so far in resolving this issue? Did you google `mac visual studio toolbox`? Did you try any solutions? If so, why didn't the solutions work? Etc... Please show some research effort such that people know what you've looked into, then they won't suggest that option again.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I searched for a fix on the internet but i didn't find anything useful, they just say to check for settings or try the reset the default ones (Already tried). Maybe these "features" are not supported on macOS. I have Visual Studio 2019 on Windows and i have everything that is missing here, the two version (Mac and Windows) seems to be completely different...